# Why are my French accents represented by question marks in my android app using webview?

Tags: android, encoding, webview

Good evening,

First off, I am very grateful to all the contributors on this website. Thanks to them, I have learnt a lot.

Now, I am very close to finalise my app. The last thing which I find frustrating that I cannot reproduce on a PC but only on an Android tablet is: when I have a webview to load which contains French accents (é, ê, è, etc..), there are represented by a question mark in a losange (I am not sure whether it is clear enough).

Does anyone has a clue what I am doing wrong here (wrong encoding?) ?

Many thanks for your contribution and best wishes,
Laurent

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    String myUrl = getIntent().getStringExtra("url");

    setContentView(R.layout.webview);

    //webview use to call own site
    webView =(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView .getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView .getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

    WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
    settings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");

    webView.loadUrl(myUrl);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
webView.getSettings().setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");
```

`webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, html, "text/html", "utf-8", null);`

Comment: Thanks. What is the html variable ? is that my url?

Comment: [Official Document](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadDataWithBaseURL%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) go through this

Comment: Thanks. For me, it does not explain me why if I set 
  `html = "http://www.google.com";`
and I run my app, only the 'http://www.google.com' is displayed on the webview.